# MicroServices and ERP

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices

I'm developing an ERP system ( logistics, WMS , Sales, etc.) in C # using DDD and I 'm trying to apply MicroServices and entered the big question:

How to organize microservices in an ERP , the responsabilides and how the core functions ?

Does anyone have any practical example ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 4):

Model your domain problem and the boundaries will become apparent. You're making the mistake of designing by technology, pattern, and framework first; instead of modeling your problem domain first and then considering consistency, concurrency, performance etc.

If you're not driving your solution by first considering the domain, you're not doing DDD.